# A Case Against the "Math Gene"

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education

I'm currently teaching a mathematics course for elementary educators (think of it as math methods, but with less focus on methods and more focus on content). In a student's essay, I encountered the phrase "one is either a 'math person' or not". That is, one's ability to do mathematics is determined at birth. Either your brain is such that you can understand math, or it is not.

This is certainly not a new sentiment, but I find it *deeply* troubling coming from the mouth of a future elementary educator. How can this person possibly be an effective mathematics teacher if s/he splits every math class into those that can learn math and those that can't?

> Are you aware of any articles, studies, etc. that dismiss the notion of the "math gene"?

Preferably, the reference will be short enough to assign as class reading. I think it is too late in the semester to assign an entire book on the subject, though it could be a possibility if I teach this course again.

The primary goal of this reading would be to convince the future teacher that an average student is able to learn math, and so is worthy of being taught seriously. I am not particularly interested in articles that show *how* this can be accomplished (that is the purpose of their math methods course), just that it is *possible* to accomplish in the average case.

Comment: You can start from [here...](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice)

Comment: I thought about that, in particular the article http://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/does-one-have-to-be-a-genius-to-do-maths/, but I don't know if it will resonate well with this group. In their view, I'm afraid they will see Tao addressing individuals who already possess the "math gene" and want to go on to do even more math.

Comment: This is similar to saying:  you are either a "word" person or not.  Either you can learn to read or not.  But those in the "not" category are a very small minority, those with *dyslexia* or other similar problem.  I have heard some thoughts of a *dyscalculia* where one is diabled to the point of not being able to learn mathematics.  But again that is a very small minority.  I think the REAL problem is that learning math is HARD and many students & teachers shy away from it for that reason.

Comment: @GEdgar This is why I used the repeated the word "average". It is possible that there really are individuals who are unable to make sense of mathematics due to some learning disorder. As you say, however, these are in the minority.

Comment: @GEdgar As for your other point, many people use their apparent difficulty with mathematics as evidence that a "math gene" must exist. "Some super-smart people understand this stuff, so they must have something I don't." The purpose of the article would be to convince them that, even in the face of difficulty, the material is comprehensible to an average student.

Comment: This certainly depends on what the student means when s/he thinks of a person doing math. On one hand, almost every third-grade boy is incapable of sitting still for an hour to memorize multiplication tables. Does that mean there are no boys who have the 'math gene'? On the other hand, an essay like "A Mathematician's Lament" would convince most people that the average person can appreciate an elegant proof (even of a trivial fact), which some argue is far closer to real mathematics than the usual K-12 curriculum. But that 'gene' is more like an artistic 'gene'. Does an 'art' gene exist?

Comment: @Bean In this context, "math" is synonymous with "K-12 math curriculum".

Comment: Perhaps http://www.amazon.com/Math-Gene-Mathematical-Thinking-Evolved/dp/0465016197 ? Generally, Devlin's argument is that most people don't recognize when they use mathematical reasoning. But it's certainly not backed up by empirical evidence.

Comment: @AustinMohr another reference is Lakoff & Nuñez - *[Where Mathematics Comes From?*](http://www.amazon.com/Where-Mathematics-Comes-Embodied-Brings/dp/0465037712/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1318714438&sr=1-1)*. I can disagree on some points forever, but they have the arsenal of arguments you might use.

Comment: Whether or not there is evidence for or against a math gene, there are certainly a ton of studies on "priming" and "attribution theory". Basically if you believe there is a math gene and one of your students doesn't have it then you will cause that student to do poorly (because you will have primed them to think they won't do well) whether or not that is true. So I can't see any way in which having that attitude would be beneficial for a teacher.

Comment: This seems like a very interesting *soft* question. I do believe that it is soft enough for community wiki, though.

Comment: "Are you aware of any articles, studies, etc. that dismiss the notion of the "math gene"?"  you should be looking for articals that confirm or deny your hypothesis, not just confirmation, hopefully the reasons why are obvious

Comment: If the ability to do math were determined at birth, then no math education would be necessary. This critique is not mere quibbling over formulation, the ill-posed question is at the heart of the problem of "nature versus nurture". I have answered the implied question on the problem of attitude of teachers and students below.

Comment: *Are you aware of any articles, studies, etc. that dismiss the notion of the "math gene"?* That sounds like a leading question. Maybe there is a math gene.

Comment: is there something like a "language-gene", guess not. everyone is capable to communicate and math is just a very rigorous kind of language, so everyone can learn it, but there might be people's abilities to concentrate and see pattern, and for this question there are enough studies. but despite this I think it very hazardously for a teacher to think this way, see this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golem_effect well know psychological effect.

Comment: If there's no math gene, and there's no secret except to persevere through difficult problems, then I'm looking forward to an explanation for those cases when it's the hardest-working prospective mathematicians who can't keep up with their academic workload (and I don't just mean the busiest, but those who actually try everything they can think of to work more efficiently), and the students who succeed are those who get twice as much done in half the time.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Lockhart's Lament might be the best reading... Unfortunately, much of the contemporary PR effort to make "great mathematicians" into "heroic figures" has played upon the weirdness of personalities, and identified common-sense mathematics with esoterica, as though it were just one remove away.

(Another hazard of L's L is that it addresses the "fine art" aspect of mathematics, rather than the common sense aspect. The criticism of the pointlessness of the usual school curriculum is accurate, though.)

First, what I view as the context... Ironically, the extreme tediousness and palpable pointlessness of (usual) school mathematics is (I suspect) what people object to, not mathematics itself. It is presented as infinitely fragile and fussy, with whimsical "rules", necessarily requiring nearly-endless drill to achieve the level of quasi-perfection necessary to "get the right answer". Blech, indeed. Why would anyone want to spend their time that way?

The genuine survival-skill mathematics that probably everyone needs to know (e.g., how to estimate things) is hard to formalize, hard to fit into "school curriculum", hard to "program" (in the sense of getting people to learn it on a regular schedule), and probably as hard to *grade* as essays in English composition. Thus, the drift away from this in the curriculum, into semi-pointless, rigid, and literally unpleasant activities is understandable, while extremely unfortunate.

Also, claiming that something requires special abilities is a seemingly-excellent excuse for not putting in the work to learn how to do it, and a ready-made excuse for incompetence, even gross incompetence. Worse, this is an excuse for future educators to not *engage* with the issues of mathematics curriculum in K-12.

As noted in other answers, genuine dyscalculia is apparently rare. Many people will grab onto such a claim just to excuse themselves... It is socially *acceptable*, even a sign of artiness or "humanity" to claim inability to do math. This is a bit perverse.

What to do? Well, one can "correct" the slogan "Some can do math, others can't", to "Some find math interesting, others don't... but everyone needs to be able to do the *basics*, to survive".

As to official studies denying the existence of a "math gene", it would surprise me if there were such things, apart from the dyscalculia notion, because the claim is diffuse and ambiguous *anyway*. Test whether some people "can't do common-sense math" "no matter how hard they try"? But of course nearly everyone *can* tell that 1375 > 892, or that 132 times 755 is bigger than 10,000, unless the very questions induce a panic-attack, which *is* the sort of thing that happens with some people. But all my experience with (college) students' panic/anxiety is that it is a result of many years' unfortunate *experiences*, not something innate. The innate aspect might be the anxiety itself...

The worst experience I've had teaching was trying to explain to future grade-school teachers the epsilon-delta version of calculus. This was the syllabus for a one-semester course required of them. No amount of cajolery, sympathy, or lenient grading could jostle them out of their apparent commitment to their belief system, their very *identities*, that they were unable to do math. It was "already too late" to talk to them sanely about it. A sad conclusion.

Not exactly answering your question...

Comment: I would like to say that there are genuine cases of dyscalculia that are not mathematically disabling. My brother has been diagnosed with dyscalculia; he used to have an extremely hard time doing simple arithmetic (he takes relatively long today also), but he still managed to pass high school maths with high marks and had little problem grasping things such as Cantor's diagonal argument when I explained them to him. It seems to me that arithmetical talent isn't related to understanding abstract concepts and reasoning.

Comment: ...and if you loved the essay, take a peek at [the book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1934137170)!

Comment: One small bone to pick: "Why would anyone want to spend their time that way?"  Because some of us were drawn to math because we liked following rules, we liked precision and quasi-perfection, and we liked calculation.

Comment: @JesseMadnick I think what paul is trying to say is similar to the following : You don't need to be a virtuoso to have a guitar at home or a keyboard to enjoy practicing and even maybe performing in a local pub. Then imagine someone comes in and adjusts your volume knobs, changes the strings or makes up excuses because it doesn't sound right. You can't even start playing let alone enjoying. That's the feeling kids constantly get from their schools' system.

Comment: @JesseMadnick And after seeing the L's L, I see that i have repeated the wonderful argument in a very bad way :D

Comment: By the way, I have no objection to precision, nor to calculation, per se. Nor to "following rules" if it means that we've ascertained how things work, and can reliably reproduce desirable outcomes. However, my recollection of my own school-math experience (say K-12) was that the "rules" were not explained, and, in hindsight, were capricious or even wrong, or, at best, _conventions_. But/and the meta-complaint is that no one was allowed to ask "why?". Finally, in many more-sadistic cases, "math teachers" enjoyed asking questions they knew kids couldn't likely answer, or constraining time... Sad

Answer (score 13):

This is a question the Canadian mathematician John Mighton addresses in his book "The Myth of Ability". He believes nearly everyone can learn elementary (pre-calculus) mathematics, and has created a teaching program called [JUMP](http://jumpmath1.org/) for elementary school students. While the program is not a proper double-blind test, it has been used successfully for many years in Canadian schools, including for the learning-disabled.

Another example would be [Jaime Escalante's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaime_Escalante) work in teaching AP Calculus to inner-city school students.

In both cases, hundreds of students who showed no aptitude or even interest in mathematics became interested top achievers.

Answer (score 10):

I think the general scientific community frowns on the idea that there is a gene which nullifies ones aptitude for learning mathematics (or any discipline). This is especially true for K-12 mathematics, which is essentially mechanical and methodical.

AFAIK there aren't any formal studies debunking this on the level of genetics, but there are plenty of authors who assert convincing arguments that mathematical reasoning *is* part of human nature in much the same way that language is. In this view, a gene stopping one from learning mathematics is as silly as a gene stopping one from learning to read or speak. Any legitimate case of this would constitute such a tiny minority to be dismissed as a general concern for a teacher.

For an example of such an author, see Keith Devlin (an experienced writer of so-called 'popular math' books) and his book [The Math Gene](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465016197)

However, if you're teaching people to teach K-12 mathematics, there is certainly no better text than [A Mathematician's Lament](http://www.maa.org/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf). This one is a mere 25 pages, so it is certainly assignable as a short homework assignment. It's an honest and unyielding criticism of the current state of K-12 education from the perspective of real mathematicians. It's certainly a bit dramatic, but I doubt your students will ever forget reading it, and it will definitely be a great source of a discussion.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps [Dispelling the Math Myths](http://math.about.com/cs/mathreform/a/myths.htm) would be useful. On the other hand, here's an [article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/education/336377.stm) which claims 420,000 students in England and Wales have dyscalculia.

Answer (score 4):

I would also emphasise the importance of finding patterns: one great school teacher I knew wrote that if you can't see patterns, then are you really alive? Do a web search on "mathematics and patterns" to find more on this.

See also our web exhibition [Mathematics and Knots](http://www.groupoids.org.uk/popmath/cpm/exhib/knotexhib.html) and the associated article [Making a Mathematical Exhibition](http://groupoids.org.uk/icmi89.html).

The aim was to show the methodology of mathematics as part of the normal methodology in which we explore and make sense of the world. This also justifies our article [The methodology of mathematics](http://www.groupoids.org.uk/methmat.html). Other issues are discussed on articles available from my page [Popularisation and Teaching](http://www.groupoids.org.uk/publar.html), for example the issue of [Famous problems](http://www.groupoids.org.uk/famousproblems.html). But the issues there are not discussed with mathematics students, to their detriment, I feel.

I am afraid many aspects of mathematics publicity, including the "Million dollar problems", do great damage to the image of mathematics.

April 23, 2017 I would like to add a translation of a part of Grothendieck's [Esquisse d'un Programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esquisse_d%27un_Programme), with my emphasis:

"The demands of university teaching, addressed to students (including
those said to be “advanced”) with a modest (and frequently less than modest) mathematical baggage, led me to a Draconian renewal of the themes
of reﬂection I proposed to my students, and gradually to myself as well.
**It seemed important to me to start from an intuitive baggage common to
everyone,  independent of any technical language used to express it,  and
anterior to any such language** – it turned out that the geometric and topological intuition of shapes, particularly two-dimensional shapes, formed such a common ground."

Answer (score 3):

I think that the one thing that always works (and is hard to do) is to make people experience stereotype threat (that is: partition the class according to some random attribute like eye color and tell them a couple of days that studies have shown that group X is better at math than group Y and then adjust your praise and expectation accordingly; change the treatment of the two groups after a couple of days).

Easier to implement: Let people take an implicit association test on a subject where they feel that they are enlightened and non-discriminating.

Everyone should know that:
1. you have to *actively* counteract prevailing prejudices to not act in a discriminating way
2. attitudes of teachers and students impact exam results significantly

Answer (score 3):

You asked for resources, so I'm posting them in a bulletted list below. These resources appear in the references of  [an article](http://heinemann.com/blog/index.php/the-mathematics-of-hope-moving-from-performance-to-learning-in-mathematics-classrooms/) (The Mathematics of Hope) written by a Jo Boaler - Stanford professor and leading mathematics educator.

An interesting research-supported statement in the article is, "One of the most damaging mathematics myths propagated in classrooms and homes is that math is a gift, that some people are naturally good at math and some are not (Boaler 2013a, 2013b). This idea is strangely cherished in the Western world but virtually absent in Eastern countries such as China and Japan that top the world in mathematics achievement (PISA 2012)."

The *Mindset* book below debunks the "fixed mindset" view of the brain (a belief that people are just naturally good at some things) and shows that a "growth mindset" (a belief that people can improve their abilities through practice) leads to greater success.

- Boaler, J. 2009. What's Math Got to Do With It? How Parents and
  Teachers Can Help Children Learn to Love Their Least Favorite
  Subject. New York: Penguin.
- Boaler, J. 2013a. "Ability and Mathematics: The Mindset Revolution
  That Is Reshaping Education." FORUM 55(1): 143–52.
- Boaler, J. 2013b. "The Sterotypes That Distort How Americans Teach
  and Learn Math." The Atlantic, November 12.
- Boaler, J. 2014. "Research Suggests That Timed Tests Cause Math
  Anxiety." Teaching Children Mathematics 20(8): 469–74.
- Boaler, J. & D. Foster. 2014. "Raising Expectations and Achievement:
  The Impact of Wide Scale Mathematics Reform Giving All Students
  Access to High Quality Mathematics," http://www.youcubed.org.
- Dweck, C. S. 2006. Mindset: The New Psychology of Success. New York:
  Ballantine.

Comment: It's worth emphasizing Dweck's book here in the comments. She has a great deal to say about perceptions of innate ability and perseverance.